# Service worker making extra call

Tags: offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to work with service workers for caching and running into an issue with authenticated calls. I'm currently using https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/ (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chriscoyier/Simple-Offline-Site/master/js/service-worker.js) as a template though I've seen the same behavior using Google's sw-toolbox.

When making a request that relies particular header parameters for authentication, it seems like the browser makes an initial request that fails, then a successful request (see image). Any thought as to why this is happening? Any other details that might be helpful?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Service Worker Fallback Required" message is [an internal error message](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477685) that is supposed to have gone away with Chrome 46. **EDIT**: It looks like it might not be fixed, though, which could be causing the problems described. We're following up on that bug.

A more general response is that you need to be very careful with how you handle service worker caching when you're dealing with responses to authenticated requests. Following general-purpose sample code will likely come back to bite you, and I'd recommend you answer the following questions before proceeding:

- Do you *definitely* want to cache the responses from authenticated requests?
- If so, do you want to use the same caching approach to *all* authenticated request/responses, or just some of them for specific API endpoints? Keep in mind that there might be API calls that only make sense with "fresh" response data.
- What mechanisms do you have in place to deal with expiring cached responses once the current user logs out/switches to a different logged in account? (If you keep responding with previously cached responses, it might look to the user like they're still logged in as the first account.)

If you're interested in one approach, you can read through the [relevant section of the case study](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/case-study/service-workers-iowa#support-for-logging-in--out) related to the [Google I/O 2015 web app](https://events.google.com/io2015/), which takes an approach that made sense to us for the type of data we were dealing with. There's some [additional code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015/blob/master/app/scripts/shed/cache-then-network.js) that uses `sw-toolbox` (formerly known as `shed`) which is relevant, too. But the answers to all those questions depend on your specific use case, so please think things through before implementing anything.

**EDIT**: Based on the comment to this answer, the intention is to avoid service worker interaction for authenticated requests entirely. If that's the case (and that definitely simplifies the answers to the other questions), then you should be able to do something straightforward like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Only call event.respondWith() if the request doesn't include an
  // Authorization header. You can swap in your own header name.
  if (!event.request.headers.has('Authorization')) {
    event.respondWith(
      // Your standard fetch(), caches.match(), etc. logic goes here.
    );
  }
});
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that if a service worker's `fetch` event handler doesn't call `event.respondWith()`, the network request will end up proceeding as if there wasn't any service worker involvement at all.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not trying to cache authenticated requests/responses. I'm trying to get the service worker ignore these requests and just pass them through normally... Thanks for the info, I'll add some more logging and post what I'm seeing...

Comment: Gotcha. I've edited my response to show how you could ignore those requests, in that case.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check that code out tonight and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: Same result :/ I changed the code to only respond to fetches for a particular resource and it still fires off the erroring call. Any other thoughts/ideas? Relevant Code: https://gist.github.com/danwoods/29abd789ededa27502b3

Comment: Can you post the code for the entirety of your `fetch` handler? Can you also try just removing that one `fetch` handler, on the off chance that there's another `fetch` handler added with addEventListener elsewhere in your code that's also in effect?

Comment: Thanks for checking back. Fetch handler code is at https://gist.github.com/danwoods/4dc19d744b753adce7a2 I'll remove the handler and let you know if there are any changes...

Comment: I'll add some comments in the gist rather than replying here.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing, but only after reloading a page that has the SW registration. I've put together a simpler reproduction at https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/097c50fea42be76a3e05 and it looks like it's just a case of updating https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477685 to indicate that the error message is still causing confusion and not consistently applied.

Comment: Still don't totally understand how we're seeing that error when there's no fetch handler...

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing that error at all anymore, whether there's a fetch handler or not. Seems like it's just a bug in Chrome, and I'll follow up through those channels.